# Custom JSON serialization for List<MyClass> with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

MyClass is as follows:

```
@Getter
class MyClass
{
    private final DateTime start;
    private final DateTime end;
}
```

I want a List to serialize into JSON with Jackson but the format is not as expected. I'm currently digging the Jackson docs but they are a bit tricky for the first read.

The JSON output is now:

```
[ {
   "end" : "2012-02-16T13:59:59.000+01:00",
   "start" : "2012-02-16T13:35:42.000+01:00"
 }, {
   "end" : "2012-02-16T16:59:59.000+01:00",
   "start" : "2012-02-16T16:00:00.000+01:00"
 } ]
```

But I want it to be:

```
[ [ "2012-02-16T13:59:59.000+01:00", "2012-02-16T13:35:42.000+01:00"],
[ "2012-02-16T16:59:59.000+01:00", "2012-02-16T16:00:00.000+01:00" ] ]
```

So don't print member names and replace inner {} with [].

Comment: Why don't you simply serialize a DateTime array and take them by pairs on the client side? If you don't want properties in the JSON output, don't serialize MyClass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@JsonValue` annotation is what you need: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonValue.html

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    @JsonValue
    private DateTime[] toValue() {
        return new DateTime[] {start, end};
    }
}
```

This tells Jackson how `MyClass` should be treated while being serialized to JSON.